# How can I prove span($AG$)=span($A$) where $A$ is any matrix and $G$ is random Gaussian Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times{n}}$ and $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times{n}}$ and $G$ is random Gaussian text matrix then how can I prove span($AG$)=span($A$)?

Comment: What's the span of a matrix?  Do you mean its column space (i.e. its range, its image)? If so, then it suffices to note that random Gaussian matrices are invertible a.s.

Comment: I mean column space, @Omnomnomnom , can you elaborate? I am kinda weak in linear algebra. Thank you

Comment: Linear algebra fact: if $B$ is any invertible matrix, then $AB$ has the same column space as $A$.  Is that what needs elaborating?

Comment: If G is not square ( so not invertible ) then when can I say span($AG$)$\approx$ span($A$), i.e. is there any condition that G must fulfill?

Comment: Yes: to have span$(AG)=$ span$(A)$, $G$ must have full row-rank (that is, it must have $n$ linearly independent rows).  I have no idea what $\approx$ could mean in this context.